# how to select nodevalue based on another nodevalue via php ?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have a xml file which contains this :

```
<ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/">
- <ns1:return>
   <ns1:mid>39824</ns1:mid> 
   <ns1:serverType>4</ns1:serverType> 
   <ns1:size>5</ns1:size> 
 </ns1:return>
- <ns1:return>....
</ns1:return>
```

Now I want to get nodevalue of mid where nodevalue size has 5, I tried following code but no results:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($file);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = '//Response/return/size[.="5"]/mid';

$entries = $xpath->evaluate($query);
```

So how can I do that ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `following::sibling` in this case. Get `mid` value where its following sibling is size with text equal to 5. Rough example:

```
$query = 'string(//ns1:Response/ns1:return/ns1:mid[following-sibling::ns1:size[text()="5"]])';
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6V95sJ)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has some automatic registration for the namespaces of the current context, but it is a better idea not to depend on it. Prefixes can change. You can even use a default namespace and avoid the prefixes.

Best register your own prefix:

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'http://example.com/');
```

In XPath you define location paths with conditions:

Any `return` node inside a `Response` node:

`//e:Response/e:return`

If it has a child node `size` node with the value `5`

`//e:Response/e:return[e:size = 5]`

Get the `mid` node inside it

`//e:Response/e:return[e:size = 5]/e:mid`

Cast the first found `mid` node into a string

`string(//e:Response/e:return[e:size = 5]/e:mid)`

Complete example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<ns1:Response xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/">
 <ns1:return>
   <ns1:mid>39824</ns1:mid> 
   <ns1:serverType>4</ns1:serverType> 
   <ns1:size>5</ns1:size> 
 </ns1:return>
 <ns1:return></ns1:return>
</ns1:Response>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('e', 'http://example.com/');

$mid = $xpath->evaluate(
  'string(//e:Response/e:return[e:size = 5]/e:mid)'
);
var_dump($mid);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "39824"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some namespace and you're trying to get the child *mid* of a *size* element whose content is 5.

try this:

```
$query = '//ns1:Response/ns1:return/ns1:mid[../ns1:size[text()="5"]]';
```

then, to see the result:

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->nodeValue . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I tried it but still no results, thanks for your efforts